# Android: decode byte array into bitmap from image with xmp

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, decode, xmp

My android application is receiving several images over http requests, which I decode using the following method:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

The main problem is that the method decodeByteArray() returns null when I pass an array of bytes of a jpg image that has xmp data. I have a copy of the image in my computer that when opened with notepad++ presents this info:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0-c060 61.134777, 2010/02/12-17:32:00">
    ...
</x:xmpmeta>
...(remaining unreadable bytes)
```

Is there any other way to convert the byte array of images with xmp into a bitmap?

Thanks in advance.